# Compiling C++ app with MySQL in Cygwin

Tags: c++, mysql, unix, cygwin

I having trouble compiling my program in Cygwin. I installed with the setup.exe program the MySQL libraries and i getting this errors  g++ compiler.

```
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/db.o:db.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `_mysql_init'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/db.o:db.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `_mysql_real_connect'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/db.o:db.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `_mysql_error'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/db.o:db.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `_mysql_errno'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/db.o:db.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `_mysql_error'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/db.o:db.cpp:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `_mysql_errno'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/db.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
```

What i do now?

Solution...
To compile this i improve my Makefile with:

```
g++ -O3 -g funcs.o db.o main.o -lm -o myprogram $(shell mysql_config --cflags) $(shell mysql_config --libs)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out I skimmed through it and I think it can help. 
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-01/msg00772.html